# jquery select click and firefox

Tags: jquery, firefox

in firefox, when i click option, firefox regards select be clicked too. e.stoppropgation() or e.preventdefault() can not solve this problem.  is it possible to stop option click event just like in chrome? Thanks for your idea.

```
<select>
<option>test</option>
</select>
<p>adfadf</p>
$(document).ready(function(){
$("select").click(function(){$("p").toggle();})
$("select option").click(function(){alert('it is weired');})
})
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
$("select").click(function(){
        console.log('select');
        $("p").toggle();
});

$("select option").click(function(e){
   e.stopPropagation();
   console.log('it is not weired');
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/GzNuf/

Comment: yes, thank you. i spelled stoppropagation wrong. very very stupid.

Answer (score 1):

Don't use click event. Use change event. Firefox is doing right, you are clicking select box.

Answer (score 1):

"click" is not the proper event for `select` elements. You should use `change` instead.